# "Unconstrained Type" error if associated type is also parameter

Tags: rust

I'm beating my head on a complex type problem, and running into issue with how type constraints work.

I want to have something basically like this:

```
trait TraitWithParameter<T>{}
trait AnotherTrait{ fn implemented(&self) {println!("Implemented and called")}}
impl<T> AnotherTrait for TraitWithParameter<T>{}
```

But that doesn't work because it requires me to declare it as `dyn TraitWithParameter<T>{}`, and that doesn't seem to actually convince rust that types I want implement the trait unless I jump through some hoops to declare them as such.

The compiler recommends making that into:

```
impl<T, U> AnotherTrait for T where T: TraitWithParameter<U>{}
```

Except if I do that, the compiler complains that `U` is unconstrained. Reading up on that error, I find it does work to do:

```
trait TraitWithAssociatedType{
    type AssociatedType;
}
impl<T, U> AnotherTrait for T where T: TraitWithAssociatedType<AssociatedType = U>{}
```

I don't understand why that works and the prior version doesn't, but more importantly I need to have a parameter on the base trait. (This is because otherwise I get conflicting implementations).

Where it gets weird is if I get desperate and try to do satisfy the constraint by doing both:

```
trait TraitWithBoth<T>{
    type AssociatedType;
}
impl<T, U> AnotherTrait for T where T: TraitWithBoth<U, AssociatedType = U>{}
```

Then it's back to complaining at me that `U` is unconstrained.

I'm struggling to understand this. How does appearing as both an associated type and a type parameter make this less constrained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining:

```
impl<T, U> AnotherTrait for T {}
```

You must make it clear to the compiler what `U` is in some way and since you can't implement `AnotherTrait` for `T` multiple times, `U` must be deducible to a singular type (based on `T`). If there are multiple possible values of `U` which can't be specified another way, the compiler will not guess or pick one for you; it will throw an error. That is what it means when an error says a type is "unconstrained": you've forced the compiler to deduce a type but many are possible.

With that in mind, its not so complicated when you consider what traits can be implemented between a generic parameter, associated type, and both.

- How many times can a `T` implement `TraitWithParameter<U>`? As many times as it wants because the trait is generic:

  ```
  struct MyStruct;
  impl TraitWithParameter<()> for MyStruct {}
  impl TraitWithParameter<u8> for MyStruct {}
  ```

  Thus `U` cannot be deduced and therefore would be "unconstrained" when implementing `AnotherTrait` for `T` where `T: TraitWithParameter<U>`.
- How many times can a `T` implement `TraitWithAssociatedType<AssociatedType = U>`? Only once since the trait is not generic:

  ```
  struct MyStruct;
  impl TraitWithAssociatedType for MyStruct { type AssociatedType = (); }
  impl TraitWithAssociatedType for MyStruct { type AssociatedType = u8; }
  ```

  ```
  error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `TraitWithAssociatedType` for type `MyStruct`
   --> src/lib.rs:7:1
    |
  6 | impl TraitWithAssociatedType for MyStruct { type AssociatedType = (); }
    | ----------------------------------------- first implementation here
  7 | impl TraitWithAssociatedType for MyStruct { type AssociatedType = u8; }
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `MyStruct`
  ```

  Thus `U` would be deduced when implementing `AnotherTrait` for `T` where `T: TraitWithAssociatedType<AssociatedType = U>` since there can only be one such `U` and can be found by `T`'s implementation of `TraitWithAssociatedType`.
- Now, how many times can a `T` implement `TraitWithBoth<U, AssociatedType = U>`? Well again, as many times as it wants since the trait is generic:

  ```
  struct MyStruct;
  impl TraitWithBoth<()> for MyStruct { type AssociatedType = (); }
  impl TraitWithBoth<u8> for MyStruct { type AssociatedType = u8; }
  ```

  Thus `U` once again is unconstrained and cannot be deduced based on `T` when implementing `AnotherTrait` for `T` where `T: TraitWithBoth<U, AssociatedType = U>`.

So the fact that `U` is assigned to an associated type doesn't on its own mean its constrained. You must consider whether the constraint as a whole can limit deduction to a single type.